# Webpy, calling a view from another method

Tags: python, view, get, web.py

Is there any way to call a webpy (GET) view (from another view) with params?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(\d+)', 'index',
    '/number', 'novo'
)


class index:
    def GET(self, number):
        return "Number: %i " % number


class number:
    def GET(self):
        get_index = index()
        return get_index.GET(3)


app = web.application(urls, globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: how can I access `web.input()` that was in `index.GET` and pass it to `number.GET`

Comment: You can use `web.input(number=number)` inside `index.GET` view and call `number` using web.input results as parameter. Just invert the example I've wrote